# WPF Controls disappearing in Windows 7?

Tags: wpf, windows-7

We have a system built using WPF and have (until recently) been developing using Visual Studio 2008 SP1 and Windows XP SP3.

We have upgraded some of our development boxes to windows 7 and we have discovered we are getting some unexpected behaviour when running our applications. Some controls do not display at all.

Has anybody else experienced issues like these and if so, how can we make them work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show screenshots with freehand circles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess [I had some similar issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566615/wpf-button-turns-invisible-on-windows-7-machines-without-visual-studio-installe) with controls (buttons in my case) that were using the DropShadowEffect. The solution was to switch from DropShadowEffect to DropShadowChrome.