# WPF: Menu items and combo boxes don't render in Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: wpf, windows-7, 64-bit

I'm trying to use an existing internal WPF application (I do have access to the source), but it was developed on XP and I'm using Windows7 64-bit.

When I click (for instance) the File menu, 90% of the time I see no drop-down menu at all.  The menu still exists - I can use the arrow keys to navigate up and down and choose an option if I happen to know the order of the options, but nothing renders at all.

The other 10% of the time, the menu or some portion of it DOES render, but as I move the cursor up and down I get graphical corruption or disappearing options until I end up back at the "no menu is visible at all" state.

This is also true of combo boxes within the application - they show no data when I drop them down, but I can arrow down and choose an entry.

Microsoft has some advice about WPF rendering issues [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/963021) but none of these steps has helped with my issue.

Edit: a coworker running Windows 7 sees the menus just fine... he has a different video card, so I'm curious whether this is video-card specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that in this specific case, the issue is only present on boxes that have a GeForce 6800 video card.  Updating drivers has no effect, but switching to a 7800 makes the issue go away.

I have no idea why this is the case, and I haven't found any information online about 6800-specific graphical issues in Win7 64, but our testing and experimentation shows this is the factor that causes it.

Crazy.

Answer (score 1):

This also sounds similar to an issue we had seen in XP, where comboboxes (or menus) would not display properly some of the time.  There is a Microsoft hotfix (for at least one flavor of it) [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943326), but unfortunately it is for XP and WS2003.  I'm not sure if this could point you in the right direction.

The link to this hotfix was found in this [MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/333d3d93-8837-42b3-a0ea-1a577485daed/).  I am not the author of this particular link, although I do remember raising this issue some time (and a different job) ago.

Comment: This does sound somewhat like my problem, but no Win7 info sadly.

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566615/wpf-button-turns-invisible-on-windows-7-machines-without-visual-studio-installe). It's probably a problem with a DropShadowEffect, removing the Effect should fix the problem.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't appear related - the machine does have VisualStudio and DropShadowEffect is not present anywhere in the app.

Answer (score 0):

I second that the issue is related to NVidia Windows 7 x64 drivers. Recently I had to replace my video card. Now I have Quadro FX 3400 with the latest drivers and am seeing similar behavior. WPF ComboBoxes don't render dropdown portions. I can only switch values with keyboard after a few attempts. It could be Direct2D-related issue. I also had to turn that off for Firefox to start working again.