# Sometimes my dropdowns/datepickers will stop functioning?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpftoolkit

Q: Where should I check to track this down?

Issue:

Opening a view model in my application sometimes makes dropdowns/datepickers nonfunctional.

ie. dropdown won't drop and the datepicker calendar won't come up

I suspect a binding issue but don't see one.

Dropdowns have normal things like strings, numbers.

One drop has a list of mini views.

Datepickers are bound to nullable dates set in the constructor of the viewmodel.

Note: These same things work in other viewmodels/views.

I can paste code, I'm just not sure what code is relevant here.

Comment: Please don't put tags in the title ("WPF/C#")

Comment: Check one thing - give focus to one of the dropdowns that doesn't appear, and then use the down arrow to "choose" something else (press enter when finished to make the selection).  If you can, it may be another occurrence of a known WPF rendering issue (I can see if I can find an appropriate link if you see this behavior).

Comment: @Wonko Yeah, I can use the arrow keys to go over the list of things w/out the drop down showing. The link will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [WPF: Menu items and combo boxes don't render in Windows 7 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653989/wpf-menu-items-and-combo-boxes-dont-render-in-windows-7-64-bit/2655056#2655056).

Sometimes simply rebooting will "fix" the problem (temporarily), but the link above will take you to a similar discussion (including my comments), which in turn have a link to an MSDN forums discussion and an XP hotfix for this problem.

Comment: Thanks. I don't see a solution for windows 7, however, we can advise users to use the arrow keys. Weird to think it is a layering issue. Again, thanks for helping me out.

Comment: You bet.  If you have an MSDN account, you may want to open an issue, as you aren't the only person I've seen (see other post) that needs a Windows 7 fix.  Perhaps there already is one, or it may be fixed in .NET 4.0 - I haven't had the opportunity to check into that.